# Run configuration missing arguments tab

Tags: java, android, eclipse, virtual-machine, javadoc

i'm newbie to eclipse, so when i'm trying to generate the javadoc the eclipse  fails to recognize packages, i tried to find a solution here and they recommend to add this path in VM options
"-bootclasspath /path/to/sdk/platforms/android-##/android.jar"
so after searching what the VM option is, in run configuration , there is no argument tab ? so how can i found it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and select the JRE used by your project. Press the Edit... button and set the Default VM arguments to -Xbootclasspath /path/to/jar.jar. Finally, click the Finish button and then the OK button on the preferences window.

Comment: /path/to/sdk/platforms/android-##/android.jar:next path:next path